# Android: listview double entries after screen rotate

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listView which is populated in onCreate(), since in screen rotate the onCreate() is called again it populates it again and thus after each rotate I get of course the entries added what I don't want. onCreate is basically:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    myList = new ArrayList<SingleEntry>();
    new getList().execute(); //Async task to fill myList

    ListView lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapterOverview(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), myList);


    lv.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
}
```

Where myList is an ArrayList and a class variable. I tried in onCreate() before the filling takes place to set a null adapter, that was what Google suggested to me. But it didn't work.

Comment: so you need to hold the array if you rorate the phone right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the `myList` in the Android's method `onSaveInstanceState` something like this:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    bundle.putSerializable("myList", myList);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
}
```

Just be sure to make the class `SingleEntry` `Serializable` by making the `SingleEntry` to implement [Serializable interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) (Note: If you have any complex data structures inside the `SingleEntry` class, you should also make them implement the `Serializable` interface). Then in your `onCreate` you can use something like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState != null) { //Check if the save instance state is not null

       //If is not null, retrieve the saved values of the myList variable
       myList = (ArrayList<SingleEntry>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("myList");

       ListView lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

       itemAdapter = new ItemAdapterOverview(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), myList);

       lv.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
    }
    else { //Bundle is empty so you should intialize the myList variable
       myList = new ArrayList<SingleEntry>();
       new getList().execute(); //Async task to fill myList

       ListView lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

       itemAdapter = new ItemAdapterOverview(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), myList);


       lv.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this on your manifest for your list activity:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

And Override the [OnConfigurationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) method on your activity like that:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
}
```

This shouldn't call your onCreate anymore.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple 'quick fix' answer:**
Call .clear() on your itemAdapter in onCreate() you could also try calling .notifyDataSetChanged() on the list adapter.

This will clear the items in the adapter before you add them again.

**Less simple but more complete answer:**
Another way to do this is to pass the itemAdapter inside the bundle in onCreate() see the section entitled 'Retaining an Object During a Configuration Change' in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html